# How to delete all files inside a main folder with many subfolders?

Tags: python

I want to delete only the files, not the folder and subfolders?

Tried this but I dont want to give examples of characters in a condition.

```
for i in glob('path'+ '**/*',recursive = True):
    if '.' in i:
        os.remove(i)
```

I don't like this because some folder names have '.' in the name. Also there are many types of files there so making a list and check those in a list would not be efficient. What ways do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`:

```
import os
for root, _, files in os.walk('path'):
    for file in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
def get_file_paths(folder_path):
    paths = []
    for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            paths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
return paths
```